# How to initialize a button from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a button inside of a fragment that I need to be able to access in the activity to change it's text. I am using this code in my main activity:

```
CategoryFragment frag = new CategoryFragment();

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_main, frag).commit();

frag.setButtonText(i);
```

The problem is the button is never initialized using the onCreateView() method (that method never even gets called) which causes a null pointer exception. I tried adding an onCreate() method in the fragment, which gets called, but I have to get the view in order to initialize my button. Since the view hasn't yet been initialized, I get another null pointer exception from the view. Here is my best attempt at the onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonFrag);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have completely misunderstood the way Fragment and Activity work with each other. An Activity mainly has the duty to "show" the Fragment, and you need to initialize the Button using your `CategoryFragment` class.

Override `Category Fragment`'s `onActivityCreated()` and then add the following:

```
Button button = (Button) getView.findViewById(R.id.your_views_id);
button.setButton("Voila");
```

Answer (score 3):

In `OnCreateView()` do like this :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yout_layout, container, false);
    button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonFrag);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Study about Activity and Fragment Interaction. This might help u. http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/

Answer (score 0):

You can use “static factory method” Refer following code

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

/**
 * Static factory method that takes an int parameter,
 * initializes the fragment's arguments, and returns the
 * new fragment to the client.
 */
public static CategoryFragment newInstance(String i) {
    CategoryFragment f = new CategoryFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("buttonText", i);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam = getArguments().getString("buttonText");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
    Button b=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setText(mParam);

   return view;
 }
}
```

and from your activity just call

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_main, CategoryFragment.newInstance(i)).commit();
```